# Reason for using homology groups in high dimensional Brouwer fixed point theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fixed-point-theorems

I'm new here and to the differential geometry. I find a problem when I'm trying to prove Brouwer's fixed point theorem using topology.

Suppose $f: D^{n}\to D^{n}$ has no fixed point, define $F: D^{n}\to S^{n-1}$ such that $F(x)$ denotes the intersection of $S^{n-1}$ and a line from $f(x)$ through $x$. In addition, define $g: S^{n-1}\to D^{n}$ as an inclusion map.

I think we can construct a map $H(t,x)\equiv t\cdot id_{D^n}+(1-t)g\circ F$, indicating the $S^{n-1}$ is a deformation retract of $D^n$ and thus they should have the same homotopy type. We can reach the contradiction that $\mathbb{Z}=\pi_{n-1}(S^{n-1})=\pi_{n-1}(D^n)=0$.

I think it might be correct in 2-dimensional case. Why do we have to use homology groups in higher dimension? Did I neglect some subtleties?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use cohomology groups, or homotopy groups. But in the latter case you need $\pi_n(S^n)\ne0$. Is that easier to prove than $H_n(S^n)\ne0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So it's because of the difficulty of proving a higher dimensional homotopy group that we use homology groups? Does it mean I can actually use homotopy groups if I take $\pi_n(S^n)\neq 0$ for granted?

Comment: Sure, you can use any appropriate tools that works. But some tools are chisels, meaning easier to manufacture, i.e. easier to prove. Others are pile drivers, meaning expensive to manufacture, i.e. harder to prove. $H_n(S^n)$ is a chisel, $\pi_n(S^n)$ is a pile driver. All right, maybe this is somewhat of an exaggeration, $H_n(S^n)$ is really a sledge hammer.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think that makes sense. Thanks so much!